# Is separate SharedAccessFilePolicy for each file is ok?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files, azure-sas

I am creating a time bound SAS for each requested file. To do that I am creating a new `SharedAccessFilePolicy` object as followings:

```
SharedAccessFilePolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessFilePolicy();

sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = expirey;
sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read;
string sasBlobToken = file.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

SharedAccessFilePolicy sharedPolicy = new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
{
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = expirey,
    Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read
};
```

**Question1:** Is it ok to create a new `SharedAccessFilePolicy` for each requested file?

**Question2:** Do we need to clean-up the `SharedAccessFilePolicy` objects that we have created or those would be destroyed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to create a new `SharedAccessFilePolicy` for each requested file like your code above, since they're all client-side operations actually. No server request happens in your code above.

You don't need to clean up `SharedAccessFilePolicy` objects above, since it's just a temporary variable to define the SAS access policy before generation.

Note that `SharedAccessFilePolicy` will be saved on server side only when you're using [Stored Access Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/establishing-a-stored-access-policy), but you're not using that feature in your code above.

Comment: @Thanks for the answer. Just wanted to confirm :)